# Do companies keep a network of informants at hand?

Tags: management

Those of you who watch Bollywood films might have heard of the movie Corporate.

In this movie, there is a sequence of events in which two rival companies are working on their products, and one company's project is valued at INR 3000 crores($600 million). A Vice President level employee is in possession of sensitive research data, but that's leaked when the employee sleeps with some girl and the rival company pays her to help them get said data.
The next day, the employee is called and told that the data was leaked. The boss even has a photograph of the girl. Needless to say, the project crashes and the employee is fired.

Is this scenario analogous to one in real life? Do companies have a 'spy' network which will be keeping them up to date with recent developments in rival companies? Or do the regular employees themselves do that role?

Comment: Highly doubtful... But makes a good movie. Money, sex and conspiracy... best combination for {Holly/Bolly}wood, but it stops there in y opinion.

Comment: only in bollywood (although various state owned organizations in various countries have access to various data acquired through various illicit efforts).

Comment: Not sure why this is getting close votes for being opinion based. Corporate espionage is a real thing and this is perfectly answerable and on-topic.

Comment: Yes. http://usatoday30.usatoday.com/tech/news/2001-05-03-lucent-scientists-china.htm

Comment: Anything goes. @jimm101 is right, the Chinese are practicing a lot of this stuff, and everybody else is doing the same.

Answer (score 7):

It's never all that glamorous, but in any industry, keeping company confidential information protected isn't easy and is a big deal.  Corporate espionage rarely involves:

- a good soundtrack
- great outfits
- very fit people who may also be able to whip out a song and dance number at a moment's notice

It can, however involve:

- people being fired for disregarding security policy
- companies losing money because their secrets were disclosed
- leaks coming both from personal connections between companies, and also overheard conversations that should never have been held off of company property
- social engineering hacks and other attacks that put intruders inside of company boundaries - both physical and digital

Do companies employ a whole separate division or similar of 'spies' to attack other companies?  I have yet to see it.  I have sat on proposals where we tried to "ghost" the other company (ie, build a proposal that is better than the competition that presupposes the moves that the other company will make) - this can be as clean and above board as simply looking for patterns in previous behavior, or as sneaky as using a collection of knowledge and insights that get into the range of "I don't want to know how you know that".

Comment: Not 'attack', just 'keep an eye on'. You know, kind of like an intelligence bureau.

Answer (score 0):

Any strategic planning group will evaluate competitors.  A lot of information is available legal in the public domain.

Where you get into a bit of spy-craft

- A company may put out some false information as unofficial
- Let's say there is a leak of confidential or proprietary data a company may try to track down the source.
- Bending the rules to get competitive data is relative. Maybe not tell someone you work for a competitor and just let them talk.
- A finder's fee is a form informant.
- An anonymous tip line is form of informant.
- Group of *informants* is bit out there.
- There are companies that (legally) mine competitive data. I guess you
  could call them informants.  You have like hedge fund managers that
  will pay for an *early* copy of a report.
- Hire a girl to get data is way out there.
- A more common attack would be network security breach. This could be
  a competitor or just a hacker.  This would be more common from a
  country where patent laws are not enforced.

Answer (score 0):

> Do companies keep a network of informants at hand?

Not fulltime I would think, but in the tender business all sorts of underhand dealings go on, since a company only has one shot at winning what might be their main project for a while and invests heavily in trying to win or find any edge. This can easily amount to subverting a competitors staff member if possible.

So I assume the same could be true in other big companies. The bigger the company and the more money involved, the less morality and playing fair are serious factors.

Comment: But won't 'playing unfair' potentially lead to legal trouble?

Comment: @cst1992 name one big successful company who has never had legal issues...